# jQuery + PHP - Croopzoom - IE not draggable

Tags: internet-explorer-7, draggable, internet-explorer-10, jquery-draggable

I'm riding a picture editor for my CMS

It works perfectly in all browsers I've tried but Internet Explorer fails.

Failure IE10, in version 8 and 7 also.

What happens is that the selection area is NOT draggable.
The red border can be dragged, but what is the area no. Why could that be?

Also, movement of dragg and drop is not "clean" ... it costs a little.

[Here the link:](http://capaesculturas.com/___pruebas/cropzoom-master/demo/)

Any idea?

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

I added this CSS to the element of "drag and drop".
You must have "background" because otherwise, Internet Explorer does not launch events for that object
(this is my logic, what I understand).

This is the CSS applied in order to "drag and drop":

```
 #crop_container_selector{
    background:url(about:blank)
}
```